# Passing PHP while variable into an external JS script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, while-loop

I have the following code:

**PHP**

```
<?php include("db.php"); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500px">

            <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY ID DESC";
              $items= mysql_query($sql);
              while ($item= mysql_fetch_array($items)){
                  $id = $item[ID]; ?>       

                  <script type="text/javascript">
                      $(function() {
                          $(".<?= $id ?>").click(function() {
                              var element = $(this);
                              var boxval = $("#<?= $id ?>").val();
                              var dataString = 'not='+ boxval;
                              $("#flash").show();
                              $("#flash").fadeIn(200).html('');

                              $.ajax({
                                  type: "POST",
                                  url: "update_data.php",
                                  data: dataString,
                                  cache: false,
                                  success: function(html){
                                      $("ol#update").prepend(html);
                                      $("ol#update li:first").slideDown("slow");                                      document.getElementById('content').value='';$("#flash").hide();
                                  }
                              });
                              return false;
                          });
                      });
                  </script>

                  <tr style="border: solid 4px red;">
                      <td>
                          <div class="<?= $id ?>">
                              <button type="submit" id="<?= $id ?>" name="not" value="<?= $id ?>">BUTTON <?= $id ?></button>
                          </div>
                      </td>
                  </tr>

            <?php } ?>
            </table>
            <div id="flash" align="left"  ></div>
            <ol  id="update" class="timeline"></ol>
            <div id="old_updates"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code works fine and allows me to insert data in sql without refresh.

But, how can I put the javascript as external script and the variables passing coretly for each item?

I want to reorganize like this:

**PHP**

```
<?php include("db.php"); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500px">

            <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY ID DESC";
              $items= mysql_query($sql);
              while ($item= mysql_fetch_array($items)){
                  $id = $item[ID]; ?>       

                  <tr style="border: solid 4px red;">
                      <td>
                          <div class="<?= $id ?>">
                              <button type="submit" id="<?= $id ?>" name="not" value="<?= $id ?>">BUTTON <?= $id ?></button>
                          </div>
                      </td>
                  </tr>

            <?php } ?>

            </table>
            <div id="flash" align="left"  ></div>
            <ol  id="update" class="timeline"></ol>
            <div id="old_updates"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When **script.js** is this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".<?= $id ?>").click(function() {
            var element = $(this);
            var boxval = $("#<?= $id ?>").val();
            var dataString = 'not='+ boxval;
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(200).html('');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "update_data.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ol#update").prepend(html);
                    $("ol#update li:first").slideDown("slow");
                    document.getElementById('content').value='';$("#flash").hide();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the script you're using currently and the example of what you want to achieve are **wrong**.
You should never mix your scripts this way. It causes alot dependencies and makes your app very sensitive for any code changes.

Don't use `id` attributes when you deal with dynamic elements. Make a group/sets of elements (that behave the same way for a specific action) by giving them the same class.

[Don't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

**Button**:

```
<button class="my-btn" type="button" value="<?= $id ?>">BUTTON <?= $id ?></button>
```

HINT: set `type=button` rather than `type=submit` attribute on your button if you don't want it to submit a form. Then you don't have to `return false;` on click.

**script.js**:

```
$(function() {
    $(".my-btn").click(function() {
        var dataString = $(this).val();
        $("#flash").show().fadeIn(200).html('');
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "update_data.php",
            data    : {'not' : dataString},
            cache   : false,
            success : function(html){
                $("#update").prepend(html).find("li:first").slideDown("slow");
                $('#content').val('');
                $("#flash").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```